# Why can I not connect to my Bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I did everything the internet said and I turned -o in the BAT file and in server.properties off! Whenever I log in with "localhost" (without the quotes of course), I get a message that says `/127.0.0.1:52268 lost connection`. Here are my server.properties settings:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Sat Feb 01 08:02:58 PST 2014
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=true
spawn-animals=true
texture-pack=
snooper-enabled=true
hardcore=false
online-mode=true
resource-pack=
pvp=true
difficulty=1
enable-command-block=false
player-idle-timeout=0
gamemode=0
max-players=20
spawn-monsters=true
view-distance=10
generate-structures=true
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

and my run.bat file says:

```
C:\Users\BridgeDell\Desktop\bukkit>java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o false

08:02:58 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.6.4
08:02:58 [INFO] Loading properties
08:02:58 [INFO] Default game type: SURVIVAL
08:02:58 [INFO] Generating keypair
08:02:58 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
08:02:58 [INFO] This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.6.4-R2.0
-b2918jnks (MC: 1.6.4) (Implementing API version 1.6.4-R2.0)
08:02:58 [WARNING] **** SERVER IS RUNNING IN OFFLINE/INSECURE MODE!
08:02:58 [WARNING] The server will make no attempt to authenticate usernames. Be
ware.
08:02:58 [WARNING] While this makes the game possible to play without internet a
ccess, it also opens up the ability for hackers to connect with any username the
y choose.
08:02:58 [WARNING] To change this, set "online-mode" to "true" in the server.pro
perties file.
08:02:58 [INFO] Preparing level "world"
08:02:58 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: -7363543960118968400)
08:02:59 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 79%
08:03:00 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: -7363543960118968400)
08:03:00 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed: -7363543960118968400)
08:03:01 [INFO] Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
08:03:01 [INFO] Done (2.295s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
08:03:19 [INFO] /127.0.0.1:52228 lost connection
08:05:51 [INFO] /192.168.0.4:52252 lost connection
08:06:07 [INFO] /127.0.0.1:52268 lost connection
```

So what do I do? I am very confused and will appreciate your help! I also have worldedit in the same directory as all the other things and it won't load! I don't see any loading worldedit messages in the run.bat thing! I will try connecting with 127.0.0.1:52252.

Comment: it didn't work, and when i tried to connect the port in the error message was 26429 then 26430 then 26431 so i connected to 127.0.0.1:56432 and instead of not being able to connect it said something like the something was bigger than i expected:something something something [8] something [0]!

Comment: The configfile and the output from the run.bat file doesn't match. The configfile says that online-mode is set to true, the bat-file uses a server/config that has it set to false.

Comment: Try re-starting minecraft

Comment: Are you connecting with a client running 1.6.4, or are you trying to connect without downgrading your client first?

Comment: Could you tell us which error the minecraft client shows? iirc "lost connection" is a generic error that can mean anything from "not-whitelisted" to "timeout". *EDIT*: I just noticed you set `white-list` to `true`. Maybe you should double-check your whitelist is correct, or turn it off for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Arperum: `The configfile says that online-mode is set to true, the bat-file uses a server/config that has it set to false.`. That's because he overrides the online-mode with the `-o` flag.

Comment: @techguy816 just because this popped up and hasn't been marked as answered, did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to your server, you need to get the local IP address of your computer unless you are connecting to the server on the same machine your server is running on.

To connect on your own computer to a server ran on your computer, connect to localhost:25565

To get your IP address to connect to your server from another computer, go to the Command Prompt and enter ipconfig, then get the ipv4 address. Then connect to Your_ipv4_address:25565

I recommend using online mode, because, as it says, it is less secure.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure it's in online mode, keep server-ip blank and make sure you port forwarded correctly. For a guide on how to port forward, go [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) and select your router.

Comment: He doesn't need to forward ports when connecting to localhost.

Answer (score -2):

server-ip=localhost

When connecting, as the IP use localhost, or 127.0.0.1

Comment: So you are saying that the OP just need to remove the port definition that will work?

Comment: I guess so, that'd be my first guess. It looks like it's rather some trivial mistake.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanna get on Bukkit you have to try getting these:

```
08:02:58 [WARNING] **** SERVER IS RUNNING IN OFFLINE/INSECURE MODE!
08:02:58 [WARNING] The server will make no attempt to authenticate usernames. Be
ware.
08:02:58 [WARNING] While this makes the game possible to play without internet a
ccess, it also opens up the ability for hackers to connect with any username the
y choose.
08:02:58 [WARNING] To change this, set "online-mode" to "true" in the server.pro
perties file.
```

gone. They will mess up bukkit servers

Comment: really? I have used bukkit in offline mode before. It worked fine. Maybe because I used bungeecord

Answer (score -3):

Go to `Online-mode=true` and change it to `Online-mode=False` and change the `server-ip=` to `server-ip=localhost`.

To connect put `localhost`.